# react native add items to array but not showing it

Tags: react-native

I am using react native function component and have a flatlist with images, when I press on an image, I want that image to be added to an array, and show that image on a view. But that image is not shown.

This is what I use (the important part at least):

```
const [ valueArray, setValueArray] = useState([]);

<Button
    onPress={() => setValueArray(item.name)}
/>

return (
    <View>
        {valueArray.map((item, i) =>  (
            <Draggable x={100} y={50} renderSize={80} imageSource={require('../../images/'+item.name+'.png')} />
        ))}
    </View>
);
```

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose item.name is a String so you cannot push a name on satValueArray function. You can do this.

```
const [ valueArray, setValueArray] = useState([]);

<Button
    onPress={() => setValueArray(valueArray.push(item.name))} // Change this line
/>

return (
    <View>
        {valueArray.map((item, i) =>  (
            <Draggable x={100} y={50} renderSize={80} imageSource={require('../../images/'+item.name+'.png')} />
        ))}
    </View>
);
```

Comment: thanks that works, I only had to change the imagesource a bit as the was an error with it.